# Ошибка и вылет в Unity

Tags: unity3d

Учусь работать в юнити и пока что только сделал объекты с врагами, инвентарь. Сейчас мне нужно сделать в помощью tilemap локацию, что я и начал делать, но затем в какой то момент юнити просто вылетает. Смотрел файл в папке crash, но никак не могу определить причину ошибки.
До этого, когда я рисовал начальную маленькую локацию в редакторе 20 года, никаких проблем не было. Возможно ли что эта ошибка нового редактора 2022.3.0 ?

```
Asset Pipeline Refresh (id=b8347e7b8d94ac34aa895b7b52ac7864): Total: 0.040 seconds - Initiated by StopAssetImportingV2(NoUpdateAssetOptions)

Crash!!!

SymInit: Symbol-SearchPath: 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.0f1/Editor/Data/Mono;.;C:\Game;C:\Game\Library\BurstCache\JIT;C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.0f1\Editor;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32;', symOptions: 534, UserName: 'Tsumi'
OS-Version: 6.3.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Опубликованное сообщение об ошибке, похоже, указывает на сбой редактора Unity при импорте ресурсов. Проблема может быть связана с конкретными активами или самим конвейером активов. Вот несколько возможных решений:

Попробуйте удалить ресурс тайловой карты и перестроить его, чтобы проверить, возникает ли ошибка по-прежнему.
Обновите Unity до последней версии, чтобы проверить, существует ли проблема.
Проверьте, нет ли в проекте конфликтующих ресурсов или пакетов, которые могут вызывать проблему.
Если ошибка продолжает возникать, попробуйте удалить папки Library и/или Temp в проекте Unity, а затем перезагрузить проект в редакторе.
Проверьте наличие несовместимых плагинов или инструментов, которые могут привести к сбою редактора Unity.
Ниже приведен пример того, как удалить ассет тайловой карты в Unity:

```
// Find the tilemap object in the scene:
Tilemap myTilemap = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Tilemap>();

// Remove the tilemap object:
if (myTilemap != null)
{
    GameObject.Destroy(myTilemap.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Не думаю что проблема в импортированных ресурсах, из них у меня только джойстик. Строчка перед crash всегда разная. Я пробовал  создать пустой проект и сразу начал делать карту, после 30 минут рисования я выбираю тайл из pallete и редактор вылетает